# Как через ajax передать данные input file

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

форма:

```
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input id="photos_upload" multiple="true" name="userPhotos[]" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif" type="file">
</form>
```

JS script:

```
$('#photos_upload').change(function(){
      console.log('uploading');
      var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);
      $.ajax({
        url: 'albums/addPhoto',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        xhr: function() {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            return myXhr;
        },
        success: function (data) {
          alert("Data Uploaded: " + data);
        },
        error:function () {
          console.log('uploading');
        }
      });
      event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Без JS работает нормально, а вот передать данные через ajax не получается

Comment: [Здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously) есть ответ, все подробно расписано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На первый взгляд у вас код рабочий. Проверьте, что у вас получается в formData, иногда с этим косяк бывает.

У меня все работает так:

```
<form name="MyForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" type="POST">
    <input type="file" name="myfile">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

В обработчике события субмит формы пишу (алерты навтыкал для наглядности):

```
var formData = new FormData($("form[name=MyForm]")[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json",    
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function( respond, textStatus, jqXHR ){
        if( typeof respond.error === "undefined" ){
            alert( "Файл загружен успешно" );
        }
        else{
            alert( "ОШИБКИ ОТВЕТА сервера: " + respond.error );
        }
    },
    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        alert("ОШИБКИ AJAX запроса: " + textStatus );
    }
});
```